# Identity Server 4 Setup

Tags: identityserver4

I have downloaded the latest Identity Server 4.0 code from GitHub.

I am using VS 2015. I start up the Host but it is generating error: 
Connetion Refused.

I am using VS2015 Update 3. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any more information you can provide? what is throwing that error? any other logs or trace you can give us?

Comment: Look at this:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securing-net-core-web-api-identityserver4-resource-owner-dalvandi?trk=mp-author-card